# vue ssr application styling breaks when upgrade to css-loader 4.0.0

Tags: css, vue.js, server-side-rendering, css-loader

**Issue**

I have a Vue SSR application which is rendering the styling perfectly OK when using css-loader version 3.6.0 but when i update my application to css-loader 4.0.0 i no longer get any styling in my application.

- With css-loader 3.6.0, when i view the html page for my application i see the "style" tag in the "head" tag of my HTML document.
- With css-loader 4.0.0, when i view the html page for my application the "style" tag is missing

*NOTE: Vue CLI was NOT used to create this project as i am doing Server Side rendering*

Does anyone know of any changes I have to make to my application to upgrade to the latest css-loader

**Styling**

My application uses inline styles in each component, i am not using any css files. Below is a sample of what one of my components look like.

```
<template>
   ....
</template>

<script>
   ....
</script>

<style scoped>
    header {
       css added here
    }
    other styles added here
</script>
```

**Dependencies**

The following are my working dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "~3.6.5",
    "dotenv": "~8.2.0",
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "~0.13.7",
    "vue": "~2.6.12",
    "vue-router": "~3.4.7",
    "vue-server-renderer": "~2.6.12",
    "vuex": "~3.5.1",
    "vuex-router-sync": "~5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "~7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "~7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "~8.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~6.2.1",
    "cross-env": "~7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "~1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "~6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "~2.0.6",
    "npm-run-all": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-loader": "~15.9.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "~2.6.12",
    "webpack": "~4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "~3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.2.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "~2.5.2"
  },
```

**Webpack configs**

I have 3 config webpack files, 1 base, 1 to create the client bundle and 1 to create the server bundle.  In the base config i have the following regarding css/vue loaders

```
  const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
  
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      // other loaders
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    // other plugins
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Discussion and workaround for SSR apps: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-style-loader/issues/46#issuecomment-670624576

This also works for non-SSR apps, but in that case vue-style loader can simply be replaced with style-loader: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-style-loader/issues/42#issuecomment-678586075